# I am trying to import openCV into android studio2.1.3

Tags: android, opencv, import, module

```
package com.example.sawsanalzoubi.vision;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
```

so in  "import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader" i have encounter the following error :

> ```
> unused import statement  
>
> import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
> ```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static  final String TAG="MainActivity";
static
{
if(!OpenCVLoader.initDebug){Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV not loaded");
}
    else
{
     Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV loaded");
 }
}
static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3"); }
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

[this is a picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdyQC.png) [this is the video that I have followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIHfqzTdOcQ)

Now here goes my errors :

```
 1)Error:Dependency Vision:openCVLibrary300:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\...\outputs\apk\openCVLibrary300-release-unsigned.apk

2)Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.example.user.vision' in default config.
```

I have tried every thing I have found 
[this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326678/android-studio-library-project-error)
and this one [a solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245603/generated-signed-apk-successfully-but-when-i-try-to-run-my-project-i-get-an-err) 
and still nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

so I ended up solving the problem by the help of [this person](http://answers.opencv.org/question/102600/how-do-i-fix-opencv-importing-errors/)

The error appears when you are trying to add a dependency which is an APK using:
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
tells Gradle to build it as an application, generating an APK using:

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
it will build as a library, generating an AAR.
for more details check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326678/android-studio-library-project-error)

Comment: but I ended up having another error                                                                     Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.example.sawsanalzoubi.vision' in default config.